# Solving several equations involving sine function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Recently, I asked for root of this equation $2x - \sin(2x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$, then i got $x = \frac{Dottie}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}$. Thanks everyone.

Now can i define a function like this: $f(n) = x$ to solving equations like this : $2x - \sin(2x) = \frac{\pi}{2^n}$ ?

Comment: What is this: $f(n) = x$? There is no $n$-dependence on the right hand side, and no $x$-dependence on the left hand side.

Comment: sorry am bad at english. I could not explain what I want. I want to define a function like this; $n$ is input and $f(n)$ equals to root of $2x - \sin(2x) = \frac{\pi}n$. I'm asking that to define a function like this possible or not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider the function $$f(x)=2x - \sin(2x) - \frac{\pi}{2^n}$$ you could notice that the first derivative is always positive (at least non-negative)  and only one root exist.

As said in  answers to your previous posts, only numerical methods could find the root. Consider Newton as the simplest; starting from a guess $x_0$, the method will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ For defining a guess of $x_0$, the use of the beautiful formula $$\sin(y)\approx \frac {16y(\pi-y)}{5\pi^2-4y(\pi-y)}$$ is a good idea but it would require solving a cubic (which, I suppose, you would prefer to avoid).

So, use Taylor series built at $x=0$; limited to the third order, you then have $$f(x)\approx -\frac {\pi} {2^{n}}+\frac{4 x^3}{3}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ and so $$x_0=\sqrt[3]{\frac{3\pi}{2^{n+2}}}$$ From here, start Newton procedure which will converge in very few iterations.

For illustration purposes, let us try using $n=3$ which gives $x_0=0.686625$ and then $x_1=0.6872046712$, $x_2=0.6866255203$, $x_3=0.6866251110$ which is the solution for ten significant digits (please notice that using the marvelous approximation would give $x_0=0.6864732880$).

Using $n=\frac 13$ would give $x_0=1.23203$ and then $x_1=1.416473410$, $x_2=1.407333885$, $x_3=1.407320604$ which is the solution for ten significant digits (please notice that using the marvelous approximation would give $x_0=1.407645988$).

For sure, larger would be $n$ and closer to $x_0$ would be the solution.

Comment: Far out dude. Nice answer. +1

Comment: Whooa newton's method again , i love it

Comment: For example, if I want to solve $2x - \sin(2x) = \frac{\pi}4$

I will define $x_0$

Then I will procedure this :
$x_(n+1) = x_n - \frac{2x - \sin(2x)- \frac{\pi}4}{4\sin^2(x)}$

Am I right ?

Comment: For sure ! Just play with that; it is amazing.

Comment: done it again. claude, you  live on maclaurin series and newtons method!

Comment: @abel. Yes I do ! You could not imagine the number of problems I have been able to approximately solve with them + Pade approximants. Cheers :-)

Comment: I have made an applet for calculating and it's great.. Thanks claude, I have illuminated..

Comment: Glad to know that ! You are very welcome.